# How to edit a JS filled input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a game for a website, I have a picture and the user by clicking can choose where the ball is gonna go.
He has 10 tries, by clicking, the user fills the 20 inputs (x and y for each tries) with unique ID like "x1", "y1", "x2" etc..

My problem is that I want the user to edit one try, by clicking an icon.

I've got a temporary solution, the values are in the sessionStorage, and when they click on the Edit button, it redirects with the id of the try and the value stored in the session, then I just fill a single input, update it on click and redirect to the 10 back.

But I should prevent reload, I need it to be as simple as I can : they click edit, they click on the pic and it edits the value. Without refreshing the page.

Here is my code, if one of you has an idea :

```
$("#imgtoCenter").click(function (e) {
selection += 1;
lastSelection = selection-1;
toAppear += 1;

var offset =  $("#imgtoCenter").offset();
var relativeX = (e.pageX - offset.left);
var relativeY = (e.pageY - offset.top);

sessionStorage.setItem('x'+(selection-1), Math.round(relativeX));
sessionStorage.setItem('y'+(selection-1), Math.round(relativeY));

document.getElementById("toAppear"+(toAppear)).style.display = "inline-block";
document.getElementById("toEdit"+(toAppear)).style.display = "inline-block";
document.getElementById("x"+(selection-1)).value = sessionStorage.getItem('x'+(selection-1));
document.getElementById("y"+(selection-1)).value = sessionStorage.getItem('y'+(selection-1));
document.getElementById("inputRow"+lastSelection).style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
document.getElementById("inputRow"+lastSelection).style.color = "#000";
document.getElementById("inputRow"+selection).style.backgroundColor = "#6C63FF";
document.getElementById("inputRow"+selection).style.color = "#000";
if(selection == sessionStorage.length) {
    for(let j = 1; j<=sessionStorage.length; j++) {

    }
}
```

});

function editTicket(id) {
    $("#imgToEdit").click(function (e) {

```
    var offset =  $("#imgToEdit").offset();
    var relativeX = (e.pageX - offset.left);
    var relativeY = (e.pageY - offset.top);

    sessionStorage.removeItem('x'+id);
    sessionStorage.removeItem('y'+id);
    document.getElementById("inputRow"+id).style.backgroundColor = "#6C63FF";
    document.getElementById("inputRow"+id).style.color = "#fff";
    sessionStorage.setItem('x'+id, Math.round(relativeX));
    sessionStorage.setItem('y'+id, Math.round(relativeY));
    document.getElementById("x"+id).value = sessionStorage.getItem('x'+id);
    document.getElementById("y"+id).value = sessionStorage.getItem('y'+id);


});
```

}

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need session storage.

You can use setAttribute and getAttribute to change the attributes of the HTML elements you are currently getting with getElementByID without reloading.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute

Comment: I'm using sessionStorage to allow my players to go back during the game process.. I've succeded fetching and updating a value from a try, onClick, it get the try ID and remplace the value on new click with a function edit(id) but if the user clicks a second times on a new try to edit it, it also update the previous values.. How can I only update the parameters of my Edit(id) function ?